# Batch or PowerShell Script Needed to Create Subfolders within Multiple Root Folders

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch-file

I have a large number of root folders (non-sequentially named), and I need a script to create a duplicate set of subfolders within each root folder, like this:

**EXAMPLE**

```
- Root Folder 1
   - Sub Folder A
      - Sub Sub Folder 1
      - Sub Sub Folder 2
      - Sub Sub Folder 3
      - Sub Sub Folder 4
      - Sub Sub Folder 5
   - Sub Folder B
   - Sub Folder C

- Root Folder 2
   - Sub Folder A
      - Sub Sub Folder 1
      - Sub Sub Folder 2
      - Sub Sub Folder 3
      - Sub Sub Folder 4
      - Sub Sub Folder 5
   - Sub Folder B
   - Sub Folder C
```

...And so on.

The subfolders and sub-subfolders are consistently named for all root folders, but the root folder names will vary.

I'm able to create the root folders within the D:\TEMP directory with output from a TXT file, via the following:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %i in (FolderNames.txt) do md "%i"
```

I'm also able to create the first level of subfolders within each root folder, via a series of PowerShell commands:

```
$folders = get-childitem "C:\TEMP\WORKING\FOLDERS"
foreach ($folder in $folders ) {
        New-Item -Name "Daily Completion Paperwork" -Path $folder.FullName -ItemType Directory -verbose;
        New-Item -Name "Final Completion Documents" -Path $folder.FullName -ItemType Directory -verbose;
        New-Item -Name "Site Documents" -Path $folder.FullName -ItemType Directory -verbose
}
```

This gives me:

```
- Root Folder 1
   - Sub Folder A
   - Sub Folder B
   - Sub Folder C

- Root Folder 2
   - Sub Folder A
   - Sub Folder B
   - Sub Folder C
```

What I'm struggling with is a separate command - or a nested command - that will create the 5 "Sub Sub Folders" inside Sub Folder A:

**EXAMPLE**

```
- Root Folder 1
   - Sub Folder A
      - Sub Sub Folder 1
      - Sub Sub Folder 2
      - Sub Sub Folder 3
      - Sub Sub Folder 4
      - Sub Sub Folder 5

- Root Folder 2
   - Sub Folder A
      - Sub Sub Folder 1
      - Sub Sub Folder 2
      - Sub Sub Folder 3
      - Sub Sub Folder 4
      - Sub Sub Folder 5
```

Unfortunately this involves a level of nesting that I haven't been able to nail down; so far I'm just creating "Sub Sub Folders" inside **all** folders, which creates a bigger problem.

Any suggestions regarding how to modify my existing PowerShell commands would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill - my apologies for the breach of protocol.  Hopefully my edits will prove satisfactory!

Comment: First of all, edit your code so all `New-Item`'s are executed in a single `ForEach`.

Comment: Then, how do you determine how many (if any) sub-sub-folders are to be created for a given sub-directory?  _I see a .csv/[PSCustomObject] in your future!_

Comment: @KeithMiller thanks, I've got them consolidated into one forEach statement (I usually clean up as a last step).  To answer your question about the sub-sub-folders, there are only the 5 sub-sub-folders.  Those are consistent for every instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific example, I would create a helper function to create each folder structure as you would like it.

Something like this:

```powershell
function New-FolderTree {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$Rootfolder,
        [string]$LevelOneName,     # name pattern for level 1 subfolders 
        [string]$LevelTwoName,     # name pattern for level 2 subfolders 
        [int]$LevelOneCount,       # howmany level 1 subfolders 
        [int]$LevelTwoCount        # howmany level 2 subfolders 
    )
    # step 1: create the rootfolder including the level one subfolders
    for ($i = 1; $i -le $LevelOneCount; $i++) {
        # LevelOne foldernames get a suffix of _A, _B, _C, etc.
        $path = Join-Path -Path $Rootfolder -ChildPath ('{0}_{1}' -f $LevelOneName, [char](64 + $i))
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $path -PathType Container)) {
            $null = New-Item -Path $path -ItemType Directory
        }
    }
    # step 2: create all level 2 subfolders in the first level 1 subfolder
    $subfolderA = Join-Path -Path $Rootfolder -ChildPath ($LevelOneName + '_A')
    for ($i = 1; $i -le $LevelTwoCount; $i++) {
        # LevelTwo foldernames get a suffix of _1, _2, _3, etc.
        $path = Join-Path -Path $subfolderA -ChildPath ('{0}_{1}' -f $LevelTwoName, $i)
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $path -PathType Container)) {
            $null = New-Item -Path $path -ItemType Directory
        }
    }
}
```

Using that function, you can quickly create each folder structure with

```powershell
New-FolderTree -Rootfolder 'D:\RootFolder1' -LevelOneName 'SubFolder' -LevelOneCount 3 -LevelTwoName 'SubSubFolder' -LevelTwoCount 5
New-FolderTree -Rootfolder 'D:\RootFolder2' -LevelOneName 'SubFolder' -LevelOneCount 3 -LevelTwoName 'SubSubFolder' -LevelTwoCount 5
```

Comment: Thanks @Theo, this helped tremendously.  It sent me down a path, via New-FolderTree, that led me to our solution!

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell notwithstanding.

Best practice, on OS file systems, avoid spaces in file, folder and variable names. You are just asking for trouble if you do this. Always use underscores as separators, or CamelCasedNames, or the like to save yourself unnecessary headaches, frustration, and hair-pulling.

A very rough simple step to be a bit more dynamic for your use case could be something like this (of course modify to the depth you are after - remove the -WhatIf if you want this to actually create stuff.):

```
# Using a single nested loop
Clear-Host
# Pass in a defined root folder array list to create root folders.
1..3 |
ForEach {
    "Creating new folder root named RootFolder$PSItem"
    New-Item -Path 'D:\Temp' -ItemType Directory -Name "RootFolder$PSItem" -WhatIf
    $RootFolderPath = "D:\Temp\RootFolder$PSItem"

    # Ask for a end boundary for sub folder array list
    $FolderCount = Read-Host -Prompt "
    For the new rootFolder $RootFolderPath, how many sub folders do you need.
    Enter a number." 

    # Pass in a defined root folder araay list to crete child folders.
    1..$FolderCount | 
    ForEach {
        "Using a sub folder count of $FolderCount
        Creating sub folder 1 - SubFolder$FolderCount"

        New-Item -Path $RootFolderPath -ItemType Directory -Name "SubFolderr$PSitem" -WhatIf
    }

    "`n"
    '*'*60
    "*** Finished creating scaffold for $RootFolderPath ***"
    '*'*60 
    "`n"
}

# Results
<#
Creating new folder root named RootFolder1
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder1".

    For the new rootFolder D:\Temp\RootFolder1, how many sub folders do you need.
    Enter a number.: 5
Using a sub folder count of 5
        Creating sub folder 1 - SubFolder5
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder1\SubFolderr1".
Using a sub folder count of 5
        Creating sub folder 1 - SubFolder5
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder1\SubFolderr2".
Using a sub folder count of 5
        Creating sub folder 1 - SubFolder5
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder1\SubFolderr3".
Using a sub folder count of 5
        Creating sub folder 1 - SubFolder5
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder1\SubFolderr4".
Using a sub folder count of 5
        Creating sub folder 1 - SubFolder5
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder1\SubFolderr5".


************************************************************
*** Finished creating scaffold for D:\Temp\RootFolder1 ***
************************************************************


Creating new folder root named RootFolder2
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder2".

    For the new rootFolder D:\Temp\RootFolder2, how many sub folders do you need.
    Enter a number.: 5
Using a sub folder count of 5
        Creating sub folder 1 - SubFolder5
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder2\SubFolderr1".
Using a sub folder count of 5
        Creating sub folder 1 - SubFolder5
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder2\SubFolderr2".
Using a sub folder count of 5
        Creating sub folder 1 - SubFolder5
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder2\SubFolderr3".
Using a sub folder count of 5
        Creating sub folder 1 - SubFolder5
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder2\SubFolderr4".
Using a sub folder count of 5
        Creating sub folder 1 - SubFolder5
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder2\SubFolderr5".


************************************************************
*** Finished creating scaffold for D:\Temp\RootFolder2 ***
************************************************************


Creating new folder root named RootFolder3
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder3".

    For the new rootFolder D:\Temp\RootFolder3, how many sub folders do you need.
    Enter a number.: 5
Using a sub folder count of 5
        Creating sub folder 1 - SubFolder5
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder3\SubFolderr1".
Using a sub folder count of 5
        Creating sub folder 1 - SubFolder5
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder3\SubFolderr2".
Using a sub folder count of 5
        Creating sub folder 1 - SubFolder5
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder3\SubFolderr3".
Using a sub folder count of 5
        Creating sub folder 1 - SubFolder5
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder3\SubFolderr4".
Using a sub folder count of 5
        Creating sub folder 1 - SubFolder5
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\RootFolder3\SubFolderr5".


************************************************************
*** Finished creating scaffold for D:\Temp\RootFolder3 ***
************************************************************
#>
```

Comment: Thanks @postanote - agreed that this is asking for trouble.  Unfortunately in this case our hands are tied by a partner company's standards, and this was the compromise settled on by our project teams!  Your script does a great job for delivering a solution that would allow the department to handle this with minimal IT involvement.

Comment: Valhalla525, I hear you. ;-} Customer/manager etc., specifications can be, let's say oddly decided, but as one who has been in IT since circa late 1970's, I've seen this and argued this many times. Yet, it is what it is. I would quote Forest Gump here, but, well, you know. ;-}

Answer (score 0):

If all the sub-folers have the same sub-sub folders, you just need nested ForEach. [Splatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7) makes the code much more readable:

```
$Level1 = 'Daily Completion Paperwork',
          'Final Completion Documents',
          'Site Documents'
$Level2 = 1..5

 Get-ChildItem -Directory "C:\TEMP\WORKING\FOLDERS"| ForEach{
   $Splat =@{
      'Path'     = $_.FullName
      'ItemType' = 'Directory'
   }
   $Level1 | FOrEach{
      $Splat2 = @{
         'Path'     = (New-Item @Splat -Name $_).FullName
         'ItemType' = 'Directory'
      }

      $Level2 | ForEach{
         New-Item @Splat2 -Name $_ | Out-Null
      }
   }
}
```